# I have Written the dockerfile for run Vue.js application using Yarn module dependency but run on machine

Tags: vue.js, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I have write the dockerfile run the Vue.js application with Yarn module but it fails .not get success last 2 day .
really appreciative for help .

Here is my dockerFile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN yarn global add http-server

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

# install project dependencies
RUN yarn install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

### Lints and fixes files
RUN yarn run lint

# build app for production with minification
RUN yarn run build


EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

After I get the logs

Starting up http-server, serving dist
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://172.30.150.240:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server

Comment: Your Dockerfile looks good. Can you post the docker run command you used?

Comment: I am trying run on docker on Kubernetes server .

Comment: This way I run docker on local machine   :   ```docker run --name s42 -p 80:8080 30aa71a11465```

Comment: Add "-d" to the docker run command. Then you should see your container with "docker ps" and access it with http://localhost